# jQuery .slideToggle() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to build a mobile friendly navigation for my website and I want to use a menu that slides down after pressing the menu link. I thought it would be pretty simple but it isn't working. When I click the link "Menu" nothing happens. It should reveal a menu using the .slideToggle feature of jQuery. If you could offer a fix or an alternative method to making a responsive and mobile friendly menu.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#burger").click(function(){
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
<!-- END OF SCRIPTS --> 

<!-- HEADER -->
<header>
    <div id="top">
        <a href="#" id="logo"><img src="root/logo.png"></a>

        <div id="burger">
            <a>Menu</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a  href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Option 3</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Option 4</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Option 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<!-- END HEADER -->
</body>
</head>
```

This is my CSS:

```
/* HEADER */
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #012d5a;
    height: 150px;
}

#top {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#top img{
    height: 110px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #B9E0F6;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}   

#menu {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 40px;
}

#menu  li {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

#burger {
    display: none;
    float: right;
}

/* Responsive Menu */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
/* define mobile specific styles here */

#burger {
    display: block;
}

#navbar {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    margin: auto;
}

#top {
    width: 100%;
}

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Where doesn't this work?

Comment: What you want is total hard to understand, still you can remove display:none from burger div class.

Comment: When i click the menu button, the menu doesn't come down. It doesn't appear at all

Answer (score 0):

Your menu is hidden in the CSS, try this instead:

```js
$("#burger").click(function(){
        $("#navbar").slideToggle();
    });
```

```css
/* HEADER */
header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #012d5a;
    height: 150px;
}

#top {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#top img{
    height: 110px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #B9E0F6;
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}   

#menu {
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 40px;
}

#menu  li {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

#burger {
    float: right;
    color: #B9E0F6;
    margin-top: 24px;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Responsive Menu */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
/* define mobile specific styles here */

#burger {
    display: inline-block;
}

#navbar {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
    margin: auto;
}

#top {
    width: 100%;
}

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<!-- Scripts Here -->
<script type = "text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- END OF SCRIPTS --> 

<!-- HEADER -->
<header>
    <div id="top">
        <div style="display:inline-block">
        <a href="#" id="logo"><img src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_images/jsfiddle-logo-thumb.png" /></a>
        </div>

        <div id="burger">
            <a>Menu</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a  href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Option 3</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Option 4</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Option 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<!-- END HEADER -->
```

Comment: Nah, that doesn't seem to have much affect but thank you for trying